# Find the smallest number bigger than the input whose digital sum is the input

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic

"Digital sum" refers to the sum of all the digits in a number.

For example, the digital sum of `1324` is `10`, because `1+3+2+4 = 10`.

The challenge is to write a program/function to calculate the smallest number bigger than the input whose digital sum is the input.

### Example with walkthrough

As an example, take the number `9` as the input:

```
9 = 1+8 -> 18
9 = 2+7 -> 27
9 = 3+6 -> 36
...
9 = 8+1 -> 81
9 = 9+0 -> 90
```

The valid output would be the smallest number above, which is `18`.

### Specs

Note that `9` is not the valid output for this example, because the reversed number must be greater than the original number.

Note that the input will be positive.

### Test-Cases:

```
 2 => 11      (2 = 1 + 1)
 8 => 17      (8 = 1 + 7)
12 => 39     (12 = 3 + 9)
16 => 79     (16 = 7 + 9)
18 => 99     (18 = 9 + 9)
24 => 699    (24 = 6 + 9 + 9)
32 => 5999   (32 = 5 + 9 + 9 + 9)
```

### References:

This is [OEIS A161561](http://oeis.org/A161561).

**Edit:** Added an additional Testcase (18)

Thanks to [Martin Ender](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender) for the [Leaderboard Snippet](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5139/leaderboard-snippet)

```js
var QUESTION_ID=81047,OVERRIDE_USER=31373;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: This title made my brain hurt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 05AB1E, <s>19</s> <s>17</s> 8 bytes

**Code:**

```
[>DSO¹Q#
```

**Explained:**

```
[            # start infinite loop
 >           # increase loop variable, will initially be input
  DSO        # make a copy and sum the digits
     ¹Q#     # if it equals the input, break
             # else return to start of loop
             # implicitly print
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=Wz5EU0_CuVEj&input=MjQ)

**Edit:** Saved 9 bytes thanks to @Adnan

Comment: `SO` is a shorter way to get the sum of digits (instead of ```J`)O```). Also, without variable assignment, you can do [`[>DSO¹Q#`](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=Wz5EU0_CuVEj&input=MjQ) :).

Comment: @Adnan. Nice! I totally missed S. Should have realized I didn't need the variables.

Answer (score 14):

### Python 2, 33 bytes

```python
lambda n:[n+9,`n%9`+n/9*'9'][n>9]
```

A direct expression. Makes a number string with 9's at the end and the remainder at the beginning. Except, for single-digit `n`, gives `n+9`.

Some outputs have leading zeroes (`099` for `18`).

Answer (score 6):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 8 bytes

```
fqQsjT;h
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=fqQsjT%3Bh&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A8%0A12%0A16%0A24%0A32&debug=0)

```
fqQsjT;h

f      h first number T from (input+1) onward where:
 qQ          the input is equal to
   s         the sum of
    jT;      the base-10 representation of T
```

Answer (score 6):

### [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina/), <s>39</s> 31 bytes

```
r`1{1,9}
$.&
T`d`_d`^.$
^.$
1$&
```

Takes input [in unary](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5343/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-unary).

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShgLisKJCoKcmAxezEsOX0KJC4mClRgZGBfZGBeLiQKXi4kCjEkJg&input=MQoyCjMKNAo1CjYKNwo4CjkKMTAKMTEKMTIKMTMKMTQKMTUKMTYKMTcKMTgKMTkKMjQKMzI) (The first two lines allows running several test cases at once and converts from decimal to unary for  convenience.)

This doesn't actually search for the result linearly, but computes it explicitly:

- If the input `n` is greater than 9, we replace it with `n % 9` followed by `n / 9` (floored) nines.
- Otherwise, we replace it with `n + 9`.

---

Using `!` (or anything else that isn't `1`) as the unary digit, I can save one more byte with the following approach:

```
^!(?!!{9})
1
r`!{0,9}
$.&
0\B
```

But this input format is a bit of a stretch, I think.

Comment: So Retina won't allow Integer input or just can't handle Integer arithmetic?

Comment: @levanth There is no arithmetic at all in Retina - the entire language is based on string processing via regular expressions, so all the arithmetic is usually done on unary representations. Retina *could* take decimal integer input and convert it to unary first, but that costs 6 additional bytes, and our policies allow unary input unless the challenge specifies decimal. (If you would rather require all answers to take decimal input, feel free to say so in the specification and I'll update my answer.)

Comment: no no its okay ^^ I was just curious about the unary input

Answer (score 5):

### Java 7, <s>68</s> 61 bytes

```
int f(int n){return n>9?-~(n%9)*(int)Math.pow(10,n/9)-1:n+9;}
```

Does roughly the same thing as many of the other answers here. Wanted to show the Java approach without using string manipulation and loops.

Thanks to FryAmTheEggman for reminding me that I'm dumb ;)

Comment: At least you outgolfed SQL?

Comment: Meh, only twice as large as most python/ruby answers here, so I don't feel too bad for Java right now. It would've been nice to beat C though :P

Comment: :/ Oops, got that from my class block. I must be rusty at this.

Comment: @Geobits It would probably beat C--.

Comment: @Fry Completely forgot about that trick. Thanks, that put me ahead of C at least ;)

Comment: What does the -~ represent? I've never seen something like that.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
`QtV!UsG-
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YFF0ViFVc0ct&input=MTI)

#### Explanation

```
`        % Do...while
  Q      %   Add 1. Takes input implicitly the first time
  t      %   Duplicate
  V!Us   %   To string, transpose, to number, sum. Gives sum of digits
  G-     %   Subtract input. If 0, the loop ends and the stack is implicitly displayed
```

Comment: Clever use of `V!U` +1 from me. That should go in our list of MATL idioms.

Comment: @Suever Yes, that gets used quite often

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES7), 32 bytes

```
n=>(n%9+1)*10**(n/9|0)-(n>9||-8)
```

38 bytes as ES6:

```
n=>parseFloat(n%9+1+'e'+n/9)-(n>9||-8)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>128</s> <s>94</s> <s>84</s> 74 Bytes

Without output, direct approach, beginner codegolfer ;)

```
def r(n):
 m=n
 while 1:
  m+=1
  if sum(map(int,str(m)))==n:return(m)
```

Comment: What code did you count for your Bytelength?

Comment: the one posted here. If I need to include the printing, I can add that as well.
I do notice that it has put spaces instead of \t, which increases my bytelength..

Comment: For starters, there are a lot of spaces that can be removed. Before/after =+() for example.

Comment: Also you can replace `print(m)` with `return m` (doesn't save any bytes but you don't have to print in the function itself). You can still print the output function return with `print(r(n))` to test your function

Comment: You can also remove lots of newlines; `m=n+1;f=1` and `if s==n:f=0`

Comment: When replacing print with return, you can do it directly in the if-statement and remove f as well as the else-statement.

Comment: thanks guys, while not really pythoneque anymore, it is a lot smaller :D

Comment: Well this is codegolf ^^ so PEP 8 doesn't count here :D

Comment: Btw you can remove the `()` in the return statement: `return m` (saves 1 Byte)

Comment: You can still remove f and just use while 1: and also remove the space between int(c) and for

Comment: @ShadowFlame I edited your title to show up in the leaderboards perhaps you would like to review my edit. Information for the Leaderboard Snippet can be found [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5139/leaderboard-snippet)

Comment: Are the square brackets needed?

Comment: @LeakyNun I think yes but he can but the `sum(...)` part dircetly in the if condition to replace `s`

Comment: the square brackets are needed yes, but I can indeed replace the s by the summing. It would save me 4 or 5 bytes I think

Comment: You can still remove the `s` variable and replace it with `sum(map(int,\`m\`))`

Comment: Great answer for a beginner golfer. But just check this will work in python. Indentation counts and your actual byte length is 84 if formatted correctly

Comment: single space indent is valid indentation for python, and it should count it..

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
<.=:ef+?
```

`=` was modified after this challenge got posted, so that it now works on possibly infinite domains, which is the case here.

#### Explanation

```
<.       Output > Input
  =      Label the Output (i.e. unify it with an integer)
   :ef   Get the list of digits of the Output
      +? Input is the sum of all those digits
```

This will backtrack on `=` until the value of Output makes this whole predicate true.

Answer (score 1):

### Actually, 17 bytes

```
╗1`;$♂≈Σ╜;)=)>*`╓
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=4pWXMWA7JOKZguKJiM6j4pWcOyk9KT4qYOKVkw&input=MTI)

Explanation:

```
╗1`;$♂≈Σ╜;)=)>*`╓
╗                  save input to reg0
 1`;$♂≈Σ╜;)=)>*`╓  first integer n (>= 0) where:
   ;$♂≈Σ╜;)=         the base-10 digital sum equals the input and
            )>*      is greater than the input
```

Comment: This answer is great because it's flirty (`;)`)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 39 bytes

```python
lambda n:[n+9,(1+n%9)*10**(n/9)-1][n>9]
```

Pure integer arithmetic.

#### Full program with output

```python
f=lambda n:[n+9,(1+n%9)*10**(n/9)-1][n>9]

print(f(2))
print(f(8))
print(f(12))
print(f(16))
print(f(17))
print(f(18))
print(f(24))
print(f(32))
```

Output:

```python
11
17
39
79
89
99
699
5999
```

Comment: I like the way that this formulation avoids the leading zero.

Comment: @Neil the other one could avoid it by using `eval`

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 33 bytes

This is a int arithmetic version that just happens to be the same as xnor's python answer. It is an anonymous function that takes and returns an int.

```
->n{n<10?n+9:(1+n%9)*10**(n/9)-1}
```

Comment: I don't know ruby that much but is the -> at the start an anonymous function?

Comment: @levanth: yes. I will clarify above

Comment: Does not work for n=9

Comment: @GB thank you for pointing that out. It is now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## C <strike>73</strike> 65 bytes

A macro with a helper function.

```
e(y){return y?10*e(y-1):1;}
#define F(n) n<9?n+9:(1+n%9)*e(n/9)-1
```

The `e` function just calculates powers of ten, and the `F` macro uses the same solving method as [this ruby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/81077/31203), and [this python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/81050/31203) answer. sadly, it is <strike>longer than</strike> about the same length as both those answers put together. But it is the first C answer.

(8 bytes saved by  Lynn's trick of removing `int`.)

Comment: You can drop both occurrences of `int`, saving 8 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

### TSQL(sqlserver 2012), <s>107</s> 99 bytes

```
DECLARE @ INT = 32

,@2 char(99)WHILE @>0SELECT
@2=concat(x,@2),@-=x FROM(SELECT IIF(@>9,9,IIF(@2>0,@,@-1))x)y PRINT @2
```

[Try it online!](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/494130/find-the-smallest-number-bigger-than-the-input-whose-digital-sum-is-the-input)

Comment: Wow! I didn't expect that!

Answer (score 1):

### Lua, 52 bytes

```
n=...+0
print(n>9 and(n%9)..string.rep(9,n/9)or n+9)
```

Meant to be saved in a file and run with the Lua interpreter, e.g. `lua <file> <input number>`

You can also try it here: https://repl.it/CXom/1

(On repl.it the input number is hard-coded for ease of testing)

Comment: What does the '...+0' do...? Does it cast the input to an integer?

Comment: Yep, to a number (Lua before 5.3 only used doubles, like JavaScript). Lua will automatically convert strings to numbers in expressions, but not comparisons. So in order for `n>9` to work properly it needs to be coerced to a number first.

Comment: +1! I see. So `...+0>9` would work?

Comment: Yep! It would :)

Answer (score 1):

## Racket 70 characters, 71 bytes

Same algorithm as most of the others pretty much. Pretty sad about not having % for modulo, or ** for expt, or integer division by default, otherwise this could be a lot shorter and I could've outgolfed C and Java. Still love the language though

```
(λ(x)(if(> x 9)(-(*(+(modulo x 9)1)(expt 10(floor(/ x 9))))1)(+ x 9)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Hexagony](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Hexagony), <s>40 31</s> 30 bytes

```
<_:->.(.+><.'!.\@"9!%>!/{.}|.?
```

Or, if you prefer your code to be a little less linear and a little more polygonal:

```
    < _ : -
   > . ( . +
  > < . ' ! .
 \ @ " 9 ! % >
  ! / { . } |
   . ? . . .
    . . . .
```

[Try it online!](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=PF86LT4uKC4rPjwuJyEuXEAiOSElPiEvey59fC4_&input=MjQ)

Thanks to @FryAmTheEggman for some ideas and inspiration :o)

Previous version: `<.:->+_.!(..'!.\><9!%>@.{.}|.?"`

Previouser version: `<><.-_|@"'!{|(.9+!8=@>{/".'/:!?$.%\1$..\`

Comment: [This](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=ICAgPyB7IDkgJwogICcgKCAuIDwgPgogQCA-ICsgISBfIEAKLSA8IC4gLiAuIC4gLgogJCAlICQgPiB9ICEKICAuICEgOiAuIC4KICAgLiBfIC4gLg&input=MzI) seems to work? Still looks golfable.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Nice work! 2 minutes after posting this I thought of a much better way to do, well, pretty much everything. Tunnel vision, probably? I'm working on a revised version.

Comment: Thanks :) Just an FYI people often chat about Hexagony in the [esoteric programming languages room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27364/esoteric-programming-languages). Join in if you want :)

Comment: Managed to smoosh it in a bit more: http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=ICAgPyB7IDkgJwogICcgKCAuIDwgPgogQCA-ICsgISBfIEAKLSA8ID4gJSAhIDogXAogfSBfICQgPiAhIC4KICAuIC4gXCB9IDwKICAgLiAuIC4gLg&input=MzI

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>38</s>  29 bytes

```perl6
{$_>9??(1+$_%9)*10**Int($_/9)-1!!$_+9}
{first *.comb.sum==$_,$_^..*}
```

<sub><sup>( apparently the direct approach is shorter )</sup></sub>

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{
  first
    *.comb.sum == $_, # lambda that does the check
    $_ ^.. *          # Range.new: $_, Inf, :excludes-min
}
```

#### Test:

```perl6
#! /usr/bin/env perl6

use v6.c;
use Test;

my @tests = (
   2 => 11,
   8 => 17,
   9 => 18,
  12 => 39,
  16 => 79,
  18 => 99,
  24 => 699,
  32 => 5999,
);

plan +@tests;

my &next-digital-sum = {first *.comb.sum==$_,$_^..*}

for @tests -> $_ ( :key($input), :value($expected) ) {
  is next-digital-sum($input), $expected, .gist;
}
```

```
1..8
ok 1 - 2 => 11
ok 2 - 8 => 17
ok 3 - 9 => 18
ok 4 - 12 => 39
ok 5 - 16 => 79
ok 6 - 18 => 99
ok 7 - 24 => 699
ok 8 - 32 => 5999
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), 456 bytes

```
,.Ajax,.Ford,.Page,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Ajax and Ford]Ford:Listen tothy.Ajax:You be I.[Exit Ajax][Enter Page]Scene V:.Page:You be the sum ofyou a cat.Remember you.Ford:You zero.Scene X:.Ford:You be the sum ofyou the remainder of the quotient betweenI twice the sum ofa cat a big big cat.Page:You be the quotient betweenyou twice the sum ofa cat a big big cat.Be you nicer zero?If solet usScene X.Recall.Am I as big as Ajax?If notlet usScene V.Open heart
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVBdS8QwEPwr@wNK3s2LnKBQEBSFQ5E@pO32GmmSM9lyd/75urtWPM4XH/I1zMzOpOynZanM5t0dK3OXcl@ZR7dDRjqC2prnDiPK5e02EmYQIrjYg3Ab2ey9L4QRKNF4UiP7mmZoWcWioyfVNKtezJtv063VUT9sGhHKHCANJwYcdI7MEwYMLcsY0nRK/sSc1mAv9hf@4yGvjMH52LNFGhT4mBN5jMR0OiDGGujgu3OpjuYArd/pkiCXQS9ddNw/fG5QqkBkZtYe1/UAJU1IMJe1Erfu3DSZTYAaXFEtH/KLwo6Jzulb87Dn3x/RZVqWqy8)

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
Æ)_Σk=▼
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7//9wm2b8ucXZto@m7fn/39gIAA)

Implicit input yay.

#### Explanation:

```
          Implicit input
 Æ     ▼  Do while false loop that pops the condition
  )       Increment top of stack
   _      Duplicate
    Σ     Get the digit sum
     k    Get input
      =   Is equal?
          Implicit output
```

Comment: I know this is an older answer, but you can solve it in 7 bytes now with implicit input (just skip the first `k`).

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), <s>57</s> 49 bytes

*-8 bytes thanks to [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)!*

```
f(n)=\{n<9:n+9,(\mod(n,9)+1)10^{\floor(n/9)}-1\}
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ijpjyktlnf)

Comment: [49 bytes](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/t1feqr0g5u). Please see this [tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243834/96039) for more details on removing `\left`'s and `\right`'s from piecewise expressions.

Comment: @AidenChow Thanks! I was originally stumped by how removing `\left` and `\right` broken my functions - turns out all I had to do was to add a `\`!

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, <s>9</s> <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
.fhsq)h
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=.fhsq%29h&input=24&warnings=0)

```
.f      - first where true:
  h     - n+1
   sq    - digital_root(^) == input()
      h - that number +1
```

Comment: Tested again, your solution gives not the correct output for the inputs 1 to 8

Comment: I think I broke it... Works except for the number `1`. Btw why does `Missing arg to Equals, evaling input` come up? I mean I give it an input number

Comment: @levanth That happens because by default the web interface has warnings turned on. I've just coded a way to turn that off (like 10 mins ago). As for why it didn't work for 1, I was checking to see if the number was bigger than 10 and if so continuing.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 10, <s>114</s> 62 bytes

```java
n->{var r="";for(int i=0;i++<n/9;r+=9);return(n>9?n%9:n+9)+r;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##XZDBTsMwDIbvewqr0qRE2QorCNGFjidglx2BQ@iyKaN1p8QtQlOfvaTpJNZeEn2xZX9/TqpRy9P@u8sL5Ry8KYOXGYBB0vagcg3bHgF2ZA0eIWe@Asilf2xn/tgCQgYdLjeXRlmwWRTJQ2VDm8nupRHiBe9SaUWWcmk11RYZbtJXnKdrFCkXVrad7Eed66/C5OBIkb@ayuyh9DpsWP3@CYoPLr0klH4t6p8ALPgAkHbEykUyxucxribl1dOEJ/3J45gfkv/0t66hPKgtIMS/6u5@HekyrmqKzz4JFciMiNYfFIkyxth/Kb9ObLs/)

EDIT: **<s>130</s> 73 bytes** without leading zeros (Thanks to *@levanth`*):

```java
n->{var r="";for(int i=0;i++<n/9;r+=9);return new Long((n>9?n%9:n+9)+r);}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##XZDBbsIwDIbvPIVVCSlRoBvdNK1kZS@wceG4cchKQIHGRYnbaUJ99i4tSFt7SfTZ1q/PPqpazY@7U5sXynt4VwYvEwCDpN1e5RrWHQIUJR4gZ6EOyGUoNZPwrAEhgxbnq0utHLgsiuS@dP2Yye6lEeIF71LpRJZy6TRVDgH1N7yFOMZwlb7iNF2iSLlwXDat7FLP1VdhcvCkKHx1aXZggxfbkDN4@NiC4lepzhZsMOgiO2C9GgBpT8zOkiE@D3Exai@eRjyaTx6H/JD8HeK/a9@@qs2gv8RNd/PjSdu4rCg@h02oQGZEtPykSNgY43Bdfkts2l8)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->                           // Method with integer parameter and long return-type
  var r="";                   //  Result-String, starting empty
  for(int i=0;i++<n/9;r+=9);  //  Append `n` integer-divided by 9 amount of 9's to `r`
  return new Long(            //  Cast String to number to remove any leading zeroes:
    (n>9?                     //   If the input `n` is 10 or larger
      n%9                     //    Use `n` modulo-9
     :                        //   Else (`n` is smaller than 10):
      n+9)                    //    Use `n+9`
    +r);}                     //   And append `r`
```

Comment: If anyone is interested: The fix would be seven bytes longer, replace `String c(int n){return""+(n>9?(n%9)+s(n):n+9);}` with `int c(int n){return Integer.parseInt((n>9?(n%9)+s(n):n+9));}`

Comment: @levanth I've edited it in. Btw, you forgot the `""+` in `int c(int n){return Integer.parseInt(""+(n>9?(n%9)+s(n):n+9));}`

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES2015), <del>45</del> <del>39</del> 33 bytes

Saved another 6 bytes thanks to @Conor O'Brien and @Shaun H.
I think I'll leave it as is, because this version differs from @Neil's answer by using `String.repeat()`.

```
v=>+(v>9?v%9+'9'.repeat(v/9):v+9)
```

Previous version (saved 6 bytes thanks to @Qwertiy):

```
f=v=>+(v/9>1?v%9+'9'.repeat(v/9|0):v+9)
```

First version:

```
f=v=>+(v/9>1?v%9+'9'.repeat(~~(v/9)):'1'+v-1)
```

Comment: `~~(v/9)` => `v/9|0`, `'1'+v-1` => `v+9`

Comment: @Qwertiy Thank you very much. I need to learn more about bitwise operators. About the second change, it looks like I overcomplicated the case for `v <= 9`. I'll think if I can return all numeric values, which could be another byte-saver (no .repeat() and wrapping return value in +()).

Comment: You don't need to name the function as per our rules

Comment: `v>9` is 2 bytes shorter, `string.repeat` will floor a decimal value no `|0` needed

Comment: Also differs from my answer by not using `**` of course.

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell v2+, 62 bytes

```
param($n)for($a=$n+1;([char[]]"$a"-join'+'|iex)-ne$n;$a++){}$a
```

Takes input `$n` then executes a `for` loop. We initialize the loop by setting our target number, `$a`, to be one larger than `$n` (since it has to be bigger, plus this ensures `1..9` work correctly). Each loop we increment `$a++`. Nothing happens in the loop proper, but the conditional is where the program logic happens. We're literally taking the target number as a string, casting it as a char-array, `-join`ing the array with `+` and then piping it to `iex` (similar to `eval`). We test whether that's equal to our input number or not, and continue looping accordingly. Once we've exited the loop, we've reached where our target number is digit-sum equal to our input number, so `$a` is placed on the pipeline and output is implicit.

---

For reference, here's the "construct a string with the appropriate number of 9's" method that other folks have done, at **67 bytes**

```
param($n)(($n+9),(+(""+($n%9)+'9'*(($n/9)-replace'\..*'))))[$n-gt9]
```

or the "pure integer arithmetic" method that other folks have done, at **70 bytes**

```
param($n)(($n+9),("(1+$n%9)*1e$(($n/9)-replace'\..*')-1"|iex))[$n-gt9]
```

Neither of which are shorter, but both of which are more interesting.

Comment: You can save 3 bytes: `param($n)for($a=$n+1;([char[]]"$a"-join'+'|iex)-$n){$a++}$a`

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 38 bytes

```
f=->n{n<11?n+9:"#{n<19?n-9:f.(n-9)}9"}
```

This answer returns a string or int depending on input size. It is a recursive solution that asks for a solution for 9 less then adds a "9" to the end.

---

## Ruby, 39 bytes

```
f=->n{n<11?n+9:(n<19?n-9:f.(n-9))*10+9}
```

For one more byte, this answer always returns an int. same algorithm as above but with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

## C, 80 bytes

```C
i;s;g(j){s=0;for(;j;j/=10)s+=j%10;return s;}f(n){i=n;while(n-g(i))i++;return i;}
```

Ungolfed [try online](http://ideone.com/40ju8G)

```C
int g(int j)
{
    int s=0;
    for(;j;j/=10) s += j%10;
    return s;
}

int f(int n)
{
    int i=n;
    for(;n-g(i);i++);
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 77 characters

```
$n=$argv[1];$m=$n+1;while(1){if(array_sum(str_split($m))==$n)die("$m");$m++;}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, <s>165</s> bytes

```sql
SELECT l FROM(SELECT LEVEL l,TO_NUMBER(XMLQUERY(REGEXP_REPLACE(LEVEL,'(\d)','+\1')RETURNING CONTENT)) s FROM DUAL CONNECT BY 1=1)WHERE s=:1 AND l!=s AND rownum=1;
```

Un-golfed

```sql
SELECT l   
FROM   (
         SELECT LEVEL l, -- Number to evaluate
                XMLQUERY( 
                          REGEXP_REPLACE(LEVEL,'(\d)','+\1')  -- Add a + in front of each digit 
                          RETURNING CONTENT
                        ).GETNUMBERVAL()s                     -- Evaluate le expression generated by the added + 
                FROM DUAL 
                CONNECT BY 1=1 -- Run forever            
       )
WHERE s=:1      -- The sum must be equal to the input
  AND l!=s      -- The sum must not be the input 
  AND rownum=1  -- Keep only the first result
```

Answer (score 0):

**Python 3 55 Bytes**

Takes two arguments that are the same

```
f=lambda a,b:a if sum(map(int,str(a)))==b else f(-~a,b)
```

i.e. to call it you would use f(x,x)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 bytes

```
@¶Xìx}aUÄ
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=QLZY7Hh9YVXE&input=OA==)

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, 54 bytes

```
$args|%{(($_+9),+(''+$_%9+'9'*(($_-$_%9)/9)))[$_-gt9]}
```

Test script:

```
$f = {

$args|%{(($_+9),+(''+$_%9+'9'*(($_-$_%9)/9)))[$_-gt9]}

}

@(
    ,(  1,  10   )
    ,(  2 , 11   )
    ,(  8 , 17   )
    ,(  9 , 18   )
    ,( 10,  19   )
    ,( 11,  29   )
    ,( 12 , 39   )
    ,( 16 , 79   )
    ,( 18 , 99   )
    ,( 19 , 199  )
    ,( 24 , 699  )
    ,( 27 , 999  )
    ,( 32 , 5999 )
    ,( 52 , 799999 )
    ,( 128, 299999999999999 )
) | % {
    $a,$e = $_
    $r = &$f $a
    "$($r-eq$e): $r"
}
```

Output:

```
True: 1 : 10
True: 2 : 11
True: 8 : 17
True: 9 : 18
True: 10 : 19
True: 11 : 29
True: 12 : 39
True: 16 : 79
True: 18 : 99
True: 19 : 199
True: 24 : 699
True: 27 : 999
True: 32 : 5999
True: 52 : 799999
True: 128 : 299999999999999
```

### Expalantion

- if `[$_-gt9]` returns a first digit and a tail

  - a first digit is the difference between $_ and the sum of 9 (`$_%9`)
  - a tail is a few nines - `'9'*(($_-$_%9)/9))`
  - finally, converts a result string into a number to remove the leading 0
- else returns `($_+9)`

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 22 bytes

```
~:x{).10base{+}*x=!}do
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v86qolpTz9AgKbE4tVq7VqvCVrE2Jf//fzMA)

Any tips are appreciated--I feel like this could be shorter.

#### Explanation

```
~:x{).10base{+}*x=!}do
~                       Eval the input (casting from string to integer)
 :x                     Store a copy in x
   {               }do  Run a do...while loop using this block:
    )                    Increment
     .                   Duplicate
      10base             Convert the number to a list of base-10 digits
            {+}*         Fold on + (sum the digits)
                x        Push x (the original input)
                 =       Test if the sum equals the original input
                  !      Negate, so the loop condition is true while the sum does *not* equal the
                         original input
```

When the loop exits, we have a number on the stack whose digit sum equals the original input. It is guaranteed to be greater than the original input because the loop, which begins by incrementing the number, executes at least once. Finally, when the program terminates, the stack is autoprinted.

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 44 bytes

```hs
f x|x>9=(2+mod(x-1)9)*10^div(x-1)9-1|x>0=9+x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hoqbCztJWw0g7Nz9Fo0LXUNNSU8vQIC4lswzC0zUEKjCwtdSu@J@bmJmnYKtQUJSZV6KgopCbWKCQphBtqKdnZBD7HwA)

Uses math. In pseudocode:

```hs
If x > 9, return:
  ((x-1) mod 9 + 2) * 10 ^ ((x-1) / 9) - 1
Else if x > 0, return:
  9 + x
```

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic, 25 bytes

```
₁₀^(iPart(Ans/9))(9fPart(Ans/9)+1)-1+9(Ans≤9
```

Takes input in `Ans`. Output is stored in `Ans` and is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
⁺µƘS=
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMiU4MSVCQSVDMiVCNSVDNiU5OFMlM0QmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0lMjAyJTIwJTNEJTNFJTIwMTElMEElMjA4JTIwJTNEJTNFJTIwMTclMEExMiUyMCUzRCUzRSUyMDM5JTBBMTYlMjAlM0QlM0UlMjA3OSUwQTE4JTIwJTNEJTNFJTIwOTklMEEyNCUyMCUzRCUzRSUyMDY5OSUwQTMyJTIwJTNEJTNFJTIwNTk5OSZmbGFncz1D)

##### Explanation

```python
⁺µƘS=  # Implicit input
⁺      # Starting at (input + 1)...
 µƘ    # ...find the first integer where...
   S=  # ...the sum equals the input
       # Implicit output
```