# Is this a Smith number?

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory, decision-problem

## Challenge description

A **Smith number** is a **composite** number whose sum of digits is equal to the sum of sums of digits of its prime factors. Given an integer `N`, determine if it's a Smith number or not.

The first few Smith numbers are `4`, `22`, `27`, `58`, `85`, `94`, `121`, `166`, `202`, `265`, `274`, `319`, `346`, `355`, `378`, `382`, `391`, `438` (sequence [A006753](https://oeis.org/A006753) in OEIS).

## Sample input / output

```
18: False (sum of digits: 1 + 8 = 9; factors: 2, 3, 3; sum of digits of factors: 2 + 3 + 3 = 8)
22: True
13: False (meets the digit requirement, but is prime)
666: True (sum of digits: 6 + 6 + 6 = 18; factors: 2, 3, 3, 37; sum of digits of factors: 2 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 7 = 18)
-265: False (negative numbers can't be composite)
0: False (not composite)
1: False (not composite)
4937775: True
```

## Notes

- Your code can be a function (method) or a full working program,
- Instead of words like `True` and `False`, you can use any truthy and falsy values, as long as it's clear what they are,
- This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so make your code as short as possible!

Comment: I had to read this: _"sum of digits is equal to the sum of sums of digits of its prime factors"_ a few times :P

Comment: @StewieGriffin: Yes, it's a rather complicated sentence, but I felt like I needed to give a proper definition instead of relying solely on the examples :)

Comment: This is one of those questions where I thought "Java+this=no", I upvoted for the idea though :P

Comment: I sometimes notice patterns in numbers, sum of digits etc., but really, do people notice stuff like this: _"Albert Wilansky coined the term Smith number when he noticed the defining property in the phone number of his brother-in-law"_?

Comment: @StewieGriffin: Yeah, it's like Ramanujan and 1729, always baffled me as well.

Comment: @BasicallyAlanTuring I should have listened to you..>.> ;P (posted a very, very long Java 7 answer)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I just pissed myself laughing hahahaaha Great attempt man

Comment: @BasicallyAlanTuring Thanks. It works, but with that everything is said.. XD Java & prime-check + prime-factors + sum-of-digits = 50x more bytes used than the current best answer, lmao. I knew you were right with your "Java+this=no", but couldn't resist trying.. ;)

Comment: @BasicallyAlanTuring Ok, managed to more than halve the amount of bytes now that I had some time to think about it.. Could probably be tweaked some more here-and-there, but at least it's lowered by a large amount (although it's still higher than any other answer..)

Comment: Do the results have to be truthy/falsy in the relevant language? If not, what determines truthiness/falsiness?

Answer (score 10):

## Python 2, <s>122</s> <s>115</s> <s>110</s> 106 bytes

```py
n=m=input()
s=0
for d in range(2,n):
 while n%d<1:n/=d;s+=sum(map(int,`d`))
print n<m>s==sum(map(int,`m`))
```

Saved 4 bytes thanks to Dennis

[Try it on ideone.com](https://ideone.com/R3ly0w)

#### Explanation

Reads a number on stdin and outputs `True` if the number is a Smith number or `False` if it is not.

```py
n=m=input()                  # stores the number to be checked in n and in m
s=0                          # initializes s, the sum of the sums of digits of prime factors, to 0
for d in range(2,n):         # checks all numbers from 2 to n for prime factors
 while n%d<1:                # while n is divisible by d
                             #   (to include the same prime factor more than once)
  n/=d                       # divide n by d
  s+=sum(map(int,`d`))       # add the sum of the digits of d to s
print                        # print the result: "True" if and only if
      n<m                    #   n was divided at least once, i.e. n is not prime
      >                      #   and m>s (always true) and
      s==sum(map(int,`m`))   #   s is equal to the sum of digits of m (the input)
```

Comment: Down voter - it might be useful to add a comment to explain why

Comment: @JonathanAllan The downvote was cast automatically by the Community user when the answer was edited. [I consider this a bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276269/community-should-not-autodownvote-low-quality-autoflags-cleared-by-edits).

Comment: The last line can be rewritten as ``print n<m>s==sum(map(int,`m`))``.

Comment: @Dennis That's a great use of chained comparison!

Comment: This doesn't actually really work, due to `4` not being printed despite it being a smith number, anyone have a fix or another solution?

Comment: @DialFrost `m>s` => `m>=s` works

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>12</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Æfḟȯ.DFżDSE
```

Returns **1** for Smith numbers and **0** otherwise. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w4Zm4bifyK8uREbFvERTRQ&input=&args=NDkzNzc3NQ) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w4Zm4bifyK8uREbFvERTRQotMTAwMHI0Mzg7NjY2OzQ5Mzc3NzXDh8OQZkc&input=VGhpcyBmaWx0ZXJzIFstMTAwMCwgLi4uLCA0MzgsIDY2NiwgNDkzNzc3NV0gYnkgdGhlIGxpbmsgb24gdGhlIGZpcnN0IGxpbmUsIGtlZXBpbmcgb25seSBlbGVtZW50cyBmb3Igd2hpY2ggdGhlIGxpbmsgcmV0dXJucyBhIHRydXRoeSB2YWx1ZS4).

#### Background

`Æf` (prime factorization) and `D` (integer-to-decimal) are implemented so that `P` (product) and `Ḍ` (decimal-to-integer) constitute left inverses.

For the integers **-4** to **4**, `Æf` returns the following.

```
-4 -> [-1, 2, 2]
-3 -> [-1, 3]
-2 -> [-1, 2]
-1 -> [-1]
 0 -> [0]
 1 -> []
 2 -> [2]
 3 -> [3]
 4 -> [2, 2]
```

For the numbers **-10, -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 10**, `D` returns the following.

```
-11   -> [-1, -1]
-10   -> [-1, 0]
 -1   -> [-1]
 -0.5 -> [-0.5]
  0   -> [0]
  0.5 -> [0.5]
  1   -> [1]
 10   -> [1, 0]
 11   -> [1, 1]
```

#### How it works

```
Æfḟȯ.DFżDSE  Main link. Argument: n (integer)

Æf           Yield the prime factorization of n.
  ḟ          Filter; remove n from its prime factorization.
             This yields an empty array if n is -1, 0, 1, or prime.
   ȯ.        If the previous result is an empty array, replace it with 0.5.
     D       Convert all prime factors to decimal.
      F      Flatten the result.
        D    Yield n in decimal.
       ż     Zip the results to both sides, creating a two-column array.
         S   Compute the sum of each column.
             If n is -1, 0, 1, or prime, the sum of the prime factorization's
             digits will be 0.5, and thus unequal to the sum of the decimal array.
             If n < -1, the sum of the prime factorization's digits will be
             positive, while the sum of the decimal array will be negative.
          E  Test both sums for equality.
```

Comment: This is a seriously cool solution I have to say!

Comment: @Emigna - It's what I did, but implemented in a far superior fashion :D

Comment: @JonathanAllan Unfortunately I don't speak Jelly so I have no idea what your code does :)

Comment: @Emigna - yeah I had planned to work out how to golf it down before adding a how does it work section.

Answer (score 8):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 19 bytes

```
@e+S,?$pPl>1,P@ec+S
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=QGUrUyw_JHBQbD4xLFBAZWMrUw&input=NjY2)

#### Explanation

```
@e+S,                 S is the sum of the digits of the input.
     ?$pP             P is the list of prime factors of the input.
        Pl>1,         There are more than 1 prime factors.
             P@e      Split each prime factor into a list of digits.
                c     Flatten the list.
                 +S   The sum of this list of digits must be S.
```

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>11</s> 17 bytes

```
X›0si¹ÒSO¹SOQ¹p_&
```

**Explanation**

```
X›0si              # if input is less than 2 then false, else
       SO          # sum of digits
     ¹Ò            # of prime factors with duplicates
            Q      # equal to
          SO       # sum of digits
         ¹         # of input
                &  # and
             ¹p_   # input is not prime
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=WOKAujBzacK5w5JTT8K5U09RwrlwXyY&input=LTI1Ng)

Answer (score 5):

### PowerShell v3+, 183 bytes

```
param($n)$b=@();for($a=$n;$a-gt1){2..$a|?{'1'*$_-match'^(?!(..+)\1+$)..'-and!($a%$_)}|%{$b+=$_;$a/=$_}}$n-notin$b-and(([char[]]"$n")-join'+'|iex)-eq(($b|%{[char[]]"$_"})-join'+'|iex)
```

No built-in prime checking. No built-in factoring. No built-in digit-sum. Everything's hand made. :D

Takes input `$n` as an integer, sets `$b` equal to an empty array. Here, `$b` is our collection of prime factors.

Next is a `for` loop. We first set `$a` equal to our input number, and the conditional is until `$a` is less-than-or-equal-to 1. This loop is going to find our prime factors.

We loop from `2` up to `$a`, uses `Where-Object` (`|?{...}`) to pull out [primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57636/42963) that are also factors `!($a%$_)`. Those are fed into an inner-loop `|%{...}` that places the factor into `$b` and divides `$a` (thus we'll eventually get to `1`).

So, now we have all of our prime factors in `$b`. Time to formulate our Boolean output. We need to verify that `$n` is `-notin` `$b`, because if it is that means that `$n` is prime, and so isn't a Smith number. Additionally, (`-and`) we need to make sure that our two sets of [digit sums](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/81071/42963) are `-eq`ual. The resulting Boolean is left on the pipeline and output is implicit.

**NB** - Requires v3 or newer for the `-notin` operator. <s>I'm still running the input for `4937775` (this is *slow* to calculate), so I'll update this when that finishes.</s> After 3+ hours, I got a stackoverflow error. So, there's some upper-bound somewhere. Oh well.

This will work for negative input, zero, or one, because the right-hand of the `-and` will barf out an error while it tries to calculate the digit sums (shown below), which will cause that half to go to `$false` when evaluated. Since STDERR is [ignored by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4781/42963), and the correct output is still displayed, this is fine.

---

#### Test cases

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> 4,22,27,58,85,94,18,13,666,-265,0,1|%{"$_ -> "+(.\is-this-a-smith-number.ps1 $_)}
4 -> True
22 -> True
27 -> True
58 -> True
85 -> True
94 -> True
18 -> False
13 -> False
666 -> True
Invoke-Expression : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is an empty string.
At C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing\is-this-a-smith-number.ps1:1 char:179
+ ... "$_"})-join'+'|iex)
+                    ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:String) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand

-265 -> False
Invoke-Expression : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is an empty string.
At C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing\is-this-a-smith-number.ps1:1 char:179
+ ... "$_"})-join'+'|iex)
+                    ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:String) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand

0 -> False
Invoke-Expression : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is an empty string.
At C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing\is-this-a-smith-number.ps1:1 char:179
+ ... "$_"})-join'+'|iex)
+                    ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:String) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand

1 -> False
```

Answer (score 3):

## MATL, 17 bytes

```
YftV!UsGV!Us=wnqh
```

Outputs [truthy or falsey](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YGkgICAgICAgICAgJSBMb29wIHRocm91Z2ggYWxsIGlucHV0cwo_J1RSVUUnICAgICAlIElmIHRydXRoeSwgcHJpbnQgVFJVRQp9J0ZBTFNFJyAgICAlIEVsc2UsIHByaW50IEZBTFNFCl1EVCAgICAgICAgICUgQ29udGludWUgdW50aWwgd2UgcnVuIG91dCBvZiBpbnB1dHM&input=MQowClsxIDFdClsxIDBdClsxIDJdClsxIC0xXQ) arrays where a truthy output requires that *all* elements be non-zero.

[**Try it online**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=WWZ0ViFVc0dWIVVzPXducWg&input=NDkzNzc3NQ)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Yes. I'm adding a bit about the definition of truthy and falsey.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>27 25</s> 23 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

(further golfing <s>probably</s> [definitely](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92059/53748) possible)

```
ḢDS×
ÆFÇ€SḢ
DS=Ça<2oÆP¬
```

Returns `0` for False or `1` for True

All test cases at [**TryItOnline**](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4biiRFPDlwrDhkbDh-KCrFPhuKIKRFM9w4dhPDJvw4ZQwqwKw4figqw&input=&args=WzE4LDIyLDEzLDY2NiwtMjY1LDAsMSwtMSw0OTM3Nzc1XQ)

How?

```
DS=Ça<2oÆP¬ - main link takes an argument, n
DS          - transform n to a decimal list and sum up
   Ç        - call the previous link (ÆFÇ€SḢ)
  =         - test for equality
     <2     - less than 2?
    a       - logical and
        ÆP  - is prime?
       o    - logical or
          ¬ - not
            - all in all tests if the result of the previous link is equal to the digit
              sum if the number is composite otherwise returns 0.

ÆFÇ€SḢ - link takes an argument, n again
ÆF     - list of list of n's prime factors and their multiplicities
  Ç€   - apply the previous link (ḢDS×) for each
    S  - sum up
     Ḣ - pop head of list (there will only be one item)

ḢDS× - link takes an argument, a factor, multiplicity pair
Ḣ    - pop head, the prime factor - modifies list leaving the multiplicity
 DS  - transform n to a decimal list and sum up
   × - multiply the sum with the multiplicity
```

Answer (score 3):

## Actually, 18 bytes

Unfortunately, Actually doesn't have a factorization builtin that gives a number's prime factors to multiplicity, so I had to hack one together. Golfing suggestions welcome. [Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=O3dgaSRuYE3Oo-KZguKJiM6jQCTimYLiiYjOoz0&input=Mjc)

```
;w`i$n`MΣ♂≈Σ@$♂≈Σ=
```

**Ungolfing**

```
         Implicit input n.
;w       Duplicate n and get the prime factorization of a copy of n.
`...`M   Map the following function over the [prime, exponent] lists of w.
  i        Flatten the list. Stack: prime, exponent.
  $n       Push str(prime) to the stack, exponent times.
            The purpose of this function is to get w's prime factors to multiplicity.
Σ        sum() the result of the map.
          On a list of strings, this has the same effect as "".join()
♂≈Σ      Convert every digit to an int and sum().
@        Swap the top two elements, bringing other copy of n to TOS.
$♂≈Σ     Push str(n), convert every digit to an int, and sum().
=        Check if the sum() of n's digits is equal 
          to the sum of the sum of the digits of n's prime factors to multiplicity.
         Implicit return.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, <s>80</s> 78 bytes

```
t=num2str(factor(x=input('')))-48;disp(any(t<0)&~sum([num2str(x)-48 -t(t>0)]))
```

Explanation:

```
factor(x=input(''))                 % Take input, store as x and factor it
num2str(factor(x=input('')))-48     % Convert it to an array (123 -> [1 2 3]) 
                                    % and store as t
any(t<0)                            % Check if there are several prime factors
                                    % [2 3] -> [2 -16 3]
sum([num2str(x)-48 -t(t>0)])        % Check if sum of prime factor
                                    % is equal the sum of digits
```

Try it [online](https://ideone.com/kMVzhE).

Comment: That `any(t<0)` for non-primality is very clever

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>120</s> 105 bytes

```haskell
1%_=[];a%x|mod a x<1=x:div a x%x|0<1=a%(x+1)
p z=sum[read[c]|c<-show z]
s x|z<-x%2=z<[x]&&sum(p<$>z)==p x
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>87 86</s>  84 bytes

```javascript
m=>(i=2,S=0,g=n=>([...i+''].map(v=>s-=v,s=S),i-m?n%i?g(n,i++):g(n/i,S=s):s==2*S))(m)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYvBDkNAFEX3vuJtykyNqUi6oY@PsBQJ0dInvBGjNk2/XSd25@TeM7Z7a7uVli1i83wdPR4z5oIwUSXGakB2VmmtKQyCWs/tInbMbYS7slhKRdFc8IWKQbCiMJSpgxu51srUIibXUkoxy6M3q2BASBRMZDdHVZ0BwwPucezApfD1AHrBEnz/POnlY9/OM@/ndYatmV56MoM4t9EQN6qR2fEH)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 21 bytes

```
&&>Q1!P_QqsjQTssmjdTP
```

A program that takes input of an integer and prints `True` or `False` as relevant.

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Q%26%26%3EQ1%21P_QqsjQTssmjdTP&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=18%0A22%0A13%0A666%0A-265%0A0%0A1%0A4937775&debug=0)

**How it works**

```
&&>Q1!P_QqsjQTssmjdTP  Program. Input: Q
           jQT         Yield digits of the base-10 representation of Q as a list
          s            Add the digits
                    P  Yield prime factors of Q (implicit input fill)
                mjdT   Map base-10 representation across the above, yielding digits of each
                       factor as a list of lists
               s       Flatten the above
              s        Add up the digits
         q             Those two sums are equal
&                      and
  >Q1                  Q>1
 &                     and
     !P_Q              Q is not prime
                       Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), <s>92</s> <s>88</s> 87 bytes

```
{sub f(\i){my \n=first i%%*,2..i-1;n??n~f i/n!!i}
!.is-prime&&$_>1&&.comb.sum==.&f.comb.sum}
```

```
{sub f(\i){my \n=first i%%*,2..^i;n??[n,|f i/n]!!|i}
$_>.&f>1&&.comb.sum==.&f.comb.sum}
```

An anonymous function that returns a Bool.

- Now does 100% manual factorization and primality checking.
- Saved some bytes by testing both "input > 1" and "number of factors > 1" with one chained comparison, since m > [Ω(m)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_factor#Omega_functions).

([try it online](https://glot.io/snippets/ei6u5x8unj))

*EDIT: -1 byte thanks to b2gills*

Comment: `2..i-1` is better spelt as `2..^i`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog (newer)](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 11 bytes

```
¬ṗ&ẹ+.&ḋcẹ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pf/ahtw6Ompkcdy5VKikpTlfRqQMy0xJziVKXa04vK/x9a83DndLWHu3Zq66k93NGdDGL9/x9taKFjZKRjaKxjZmamE29kZqpjoGOoY2JpbG5ubhoLAA)

Predicate succeeds if the input is a Smith number and fails if it is not.

```
               The input
¬ṗ             is not prime,
  &            and the input's 
   ẹ           digits
    +          sum to
     .         the output variable,
      &        and the input's 
       ḋ       prime factors' (getting prime factors of a number < 1 fails)
        c      concatenated
         ẹ     digits
          +    sum to
               the output variable.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>14</s> 11 bytes

```
ìx ¥Uk x_ìx
```

*-3 bytes thanks to @Shaggy*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///CaCoVDS0OzFSrigcz//42MAA)

Comment: [11 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///CaCoVDS0OzFSrigcz//42MAA)

Comment: Note to self: need to remember which functions can be passed functions

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>36</s> 29 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

This answer owes its golfiness to Extended's `⍭` monad for returning the prime factors of a number, and that `⊤` is better at base-conversion than in Dyalog Unicode.

Edit: -7 bytes thanks to dzaima.

```apl
{2>⍵:0⋄(⊃=+/-⊃×2<≢)+⌿10⊤⍵,⍭⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/v9rI7lHvViuDR90tGo@6mm219XWB1OHpRjaPOhdpaj/q2W9o8KhrCVCNzqPetUCq9n/ao7YJj3r7HvVN9fQHqj203vhR20QgLzjIGUiGeHgG/087tMLQQsHISMHQWMHMzEzh0HojM1MFAwVDBRNLY3Nzc1MA)

**Explanation**

```apl
{1⋄(3)2}  A dfn, a function in brackets. ⋄ is a statement separator.
          The numbers signify the sections in the order they are explained.

2>⍵:0  If we have a number less than 2,
       we immediately return 0 to avoid a DOMAIN ERROR.

+⌿10⊤⍵,⍭⍵
        ⍭⍵  We take the factors of ⍵, our input as our right argument,
      ⍵,    and append it to our input again.
   10⊤      before converting the input and its factors into a matrix of their base-10 digits
            (each row is the places, units, tens, hundreds, etc.)
+⌿         And taking their sum across the columns of the resulting matrix,
            to give us the sum of their digits, their digit-sums.

(⊃=+/-⊃×2<≢)  We run this section over the list of sums of digits above.
 ⊃=+/-⊃       We check if the main digit-sum (of our input)
               Is equal to the sum of our digit-sums
               (minus our main digit-sum that is also still in the list)
        ×2<≢   The trick here is that we can sneak in our composite check
               (if our input is prime there will be only two numbers, 
               the digit-sum of the prime,
               and the digit-sum of its sole prime factor, itself)
               So if we have a prime, we zero our (minus our main sum)
               in the calculation above, so that primes will not succeed in the check.
               We return the result of the check.
```

Comment: 29 bytes - `{2>⍵:0⋄(⊃=+/-⊃×2<≢)+⌿10⊤⍵,⍭⍵}`

Answer (score 2):

## [Rutger](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Rutger), 504 bytes

```
x=$Input;
t=Not[IsPrime[$x]];
c=();
d=p=0;
i=IfElse[{l=LessThan[$x];l[1]}];
i=i[{t=0;}];
i=i[{s=Array[Str[$x]];e=Each[$s];e=e[@i];e=e[{a=Add[$d];d=a[Integer[$i]];}];Do[$e];r=2;w=While[{Decrement[$x];}];w=w[{i=IfElse[{m=Modulo[$x];Not[m[$r]];}];i=i[{a=Append[$c];v=Divide[$x];x=Integer[v[$r]];c=a[Array[Str[$r]]];}];i=i[{r=Increment[$r];}];Do[$i];}];Do[$w];h=Each[$c];h=h[@k];h=h[{l=Each[$k];l=l[@n];l=l[{a=Add[$p];p=a[Integer[$n]];}];Do[$l];}];Do[$h];}];
Do[$i];
z=Times[$t];
e=Equal[$d];
Print[z[e[$p]];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVFNa8MwDL37d/iw3fZJGUbQQnsIbGOwwg7ChxB7i5njZLbTdA377ZkSt2lPepKlp6dn38Yv7YdhDzxzTRsFi/BaR8zCmzeVRr6XUrACrq4FU9DAjWAGss@NDRp7C886hG2Zu7FPWLyVf3JsMNhHap2TACvv8198jz4xatjkRYk8jFDj0qTY57BSCrmSQkGOmYua1CE3NEJk6xq5lsLDnejgozSWJta68LrSLk4SqKmDDvuzxgpeatXaenoeL6uQ@0Q3SaONTaMdLS2k2MHa7IyazhZ7OO3fpZGCJF3cQaUzjafmWYif1ZoZdVKUx6OLEZa4/E6RbEx1yi1YXLoUT2Y0UjSXZrizGXZG5YTYcSc7wJZ@LyCPlJDZP21uJ1sZfStJPKAeiaUYhoen@8Vi8fgP)

Rutger isn't a particularly short language, and doesn't excel at having to split an integer into its constituent digits.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 26 bytes

```apl
(×/≡⍥(+/⍣≡10⊤⊢)⊢×1<≢)⍭⍤⌈∘2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/X@PwdP1HnQsf9S7V0NZ/1LsYyDY0eNS15FHXIk0gPjzd0OZRJ5DZu/ZR75JHPR2POmYY/U971DbhUW/fo76pnv6PupoPrTd@1DYRyAsOcgaSIR6ewf@BtHOkenFiTom6wqPuFoXUvMSknNRgR58Qrtik/IrMvHSF/DyutEMrDC0UjIwUDI0VzMzMFA6tNzIzVTBQMFQwsTQ2Nzc3BQA)

A golfed version of [Sherlock9's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180810/78410). A nice use case for Over `f⍥g`, which performs `g` on both sides and combines the two with `f`.

#### How it works

```apl
(×/≡⍥(+/⍣≡10⊤⊢)⊢×1<≢)⍭⍤⌈∘2  ⍝ Input: n
                       ⌈∘2  ⍝ max(n,2)
                     ⍭⍤     ⍝ Prime factorization of above
(              ⊢×1<≢)       ⍝ Side 1: if n is not composite, multiply ^ with zero
 ×/                         ⍝ Side 2: multiply all primes to get original number
    ⍥(        )  ⍝ Operate on each side..
          10⊤⊢   ⍝ Base-10 digits of each number
      +/⍣≡       ⍝ Sum all of them
   ≡             ⍝ Check equality of the two sides
```

Answer (score 2):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 131 bytes

```
(load library
(d F(q((X)(*(*(not(prime? X))X)(e(sum(to-base 10 X))(sum(map(q((X)(s X 48)))(chars(join(map string(prime-factors X))(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzbDoIwDIbveYpediYazuKVdzwDtwMmzuyA3dDw9DiGadIv/dq/XppVSTdvGyrLR1CyJ05rgiO0@EbsGJ5CGetxJqnFHTrGghToFo3ennvuBGTprqPSfP7nHHRQNiz44cnJ4ctKs6/BeZJmOv6dH3zwllzMb9hC1rAkIM8jsiKirutINGKCvK5YnNLjJPTBai2MhzCWt@J6rRj4p3TwlUoBLQYelsRH0IUl2w8)

An unintentional golf at `join` which through some weird behaviour ends up producing the right thing. Rest of it is just the formula given in the question.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 63 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 7.875 bytes

```
₍‡ǐvffṠṠ≈
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwi4oKN4oChx5B2ZmbhuaDhuaDiiYgiLCIiLCIyOCJd)

Bitstring:

```
110001111001001111101010000010100001001101010011001110100101010
```

```
₍‡ǐvffṠṠ≈­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
₍          # ‎⁡Wrap the next to items in a list
 ‡ǐvf      # ‎⁢list of digits for each prime factor
     f     # ‎⁣list of digits of original number
      ṠṠ   # ‎⁤vectorised sum twice (quirk of list depth from digit lists)
        ≈  # ‎⁢⁡are they equal
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 16 bytes

```
Pm[`mbs(sQ[qRlt*
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=Pm%5B%60mbs%28sQ%5BqRlt%2a&input=22)

Comment: Errors without result for input less than `2`

Comment: @JonathanAllan no output to stdout is falsy. If warnings are disabled stderr gets ignored too

Comment: I knew we can ignore stderr, but no output seems a bit weird ...but if it's acceptable then it's acceptable.

Comment: Personally I'm not sure if it's acceptable but I can say it is right?

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, <s>509</s> <s>506</s> <s>435</s> <s>426</s> <s>419</s> 230 bytes

```
boolean c(int n){return n<2|p(n)?0>1:d(n)==f(n);}int d(int n){return n>9?n%10+d(n/10):n;}int f(int n){int r=0,i;for(i=1;++i<=n;)for(;n%i<1;n/=i,r+=i>9?d(i):i);return r;}boolean p(int n){int i=2;while(i<n)n=n%i++<1?0:n;return n>1;}
```

I should have listened to *@BasicallyAlanTuring*'s comment..

> This is one of those questions where I thought "Java+this=no", I upvoted for the idea though :P

Ah well.. Some programming languages use a single byte for the prime-factors or prime-check, but Java is certainly not one of them.

EDIT: Halved the amount of bytes now that I had some time to think about it.

**Ungolfed (sort-off..) & test cases:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/1ihqJd)

```
class M{
  static boolean c(int n){
    return n < 2 | p(n)
            ? 0 > 1 //false
            : d(n) == f(n);
  }

  // Sums digits of int
  static int d(int n) {
    return n > 9
            ? n%10 + d(n/10)
            : n;
  }

  // Convert int to sum of prime-factors
  static int f(int n) {
    int r = 0,
        i;
    for(i = 1; ++i <= n; ){
      for( ; n % i < 1; n /= i,
                        r += i > 9 ? d(i) : i);
    }
    return r;
  }

  // Checks if the int is a prime
  static boolean p(int n){
    int i = 2;
    while(i < n){
      n = n % i++ < 1
           ? 0
           : n;
    }
    return n > 1;
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c(18));
    System.out.println(c(22));
    System.out.println(c(13));
    System.out.println(c(666));
    System.out.println(c(-256));
    System.out.println(c(0));
    System.out.println(c(1));
    System.out.println(c(4937775));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
false
true
false
true
false
false
false
true
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>31</s></sup> 30 bytes

```
0&p:*](=+/)&(1#."."0@":)q: ::1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DdQKrLRiNWy19TXVNAyV9ZT0lAwclKw0C60UrKwM/2sqcHGlJmfkA3XYKqQpGCBzDFE4Fig8Y2RevJGZKRfUHEOwiJERMs/MzAyZa2JpbG5ubsr1HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>139</s> 136 bytes

```c
S(m,i,t,h,_){t=m=m<2?2:m;for(_=h=i=1;m>1;h=1){while(m%++h);for(m/=h;i+=h%10,h/=10;);}while(t%++h);for(m=t;_+=m%10,m/=10;);m=t-h?i==_:0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcrBCsIwEATQu18RhEJiU2w89OC69iM8qoQStRtwq4Sgh9Jvj2314JyGmeeK1rmUDpK111GTtqqPyMi7Tb3ZMtweQVok9GiA9wYIjerf5O9XyVmek5oFr5HA50iZKTWt0ZSgYPiy@Mcwgs2RJ8U/NW4F1R7RbksYku@i4MZ3cipNaJ0WjpogVmN/Hc@qX4gxzzDeN7nMLqduqcVBNvHh5UzMWSkFiyGlqqo@)

-3 bytes thanks to ceilingcat

Explanation:

```c
/* 
 * Variable mappings:
 *  is_smith      => S
 *  argument      => m
 *  factor_digits => i
 *  arg_copy      => t
 *  least_factor  => h
 *  digit_sum     => _    
 */
int is_smith(int argument){                     /* S(m,i,t,h,_){ */
    int factor_digits;
    int arg_copy;
    int least_factor;
    int digit_sum;

    /* 
     * The cases of 0 and 1 are degenerate. 
     * Mapping them to a non-degenerate case with the right result.
     */
    if (argument < 2) {                         /* t=m=m<2?2:m; */
        argument = 2;
    }
    arg_copy = argument;

    /* 
     * Initializing these to 1 instead of zero is done for golf reasons.
     * In the end we just compare them, so it doesn't really matter.
     */
    factor_digits = 1;                          /* for(_=h=i=1; */
    digit_sum = 1;

    /* Loop over each prime factor of argument */
    while (argument > 1) {                      /* m>1; */

        /*
         * Find the smallest factor 
         * Note that it is initialized to 1 in the golfed version since prefix
         * increment is used in the modulus operation.
         */
        least_factor = 2;                       /* h=1){ */
        while (argument % least_factor != 0)    /* while(m% */
            least_factor++;                     /* ++h); */
        argument /= least_factor;               /* for(m/=h; */

        /* Add its digit sum to factor_digits */
        while (least_factor > 0) {
            factor_digits += least_factor % 10; /* i+=h%10, */
            least_factor /= 10;                 /* h/=10;) */
        }                                       /* ; */

    }                                           /* } */

    /* In the golfed version we get this for free in the for loop. */
    least_factor = 2;
    while (arg_copy % least_factor != 0)        /* while(t% */
        least_factor++;                         /* ++h); */

    /* Restore the argument */
    argument = arg_copy;                        /* for(m=t; */

    /* Compute the arguments digit sum */
    while (argument > 0) {
        digit_sum += argument % 10;             /* _+=m%10, */
        argument /= 10;                         /* m/=10;) */
    }                                           /* ; */

    /* This return is done by assigning to first argument when golfed. */
                                                /* m= */
    if (arg_copy == least_factor) {             /* t==h? */
        return 0; /* prime input */             /* 0 */
    } else {                                    /* : */
        return digit_sum == factor_digits;      /* i == _ */
    }                                           /* ; */
}                                               /* } */
```

Comment: That introduced a few bugs (e.g. 2 and 3) but I think it should still be achievable.

Comment: Suggest `t-h&&i==_` instead of `t-h?i==_:0`

Answer (score 0):

## Racket 176 bytes

```
(define(sd x)(if(= x 0)0(+(modulo x 10)(sd(/(- x(modulo x 10))10)))))
(require math)(define(f N)
(if(=(for/sum((i(factorize N)))(*(sd(list-ref i 0))(list-ref i 1)))(sd N))1 0))
```

Returns 1 if true and 0 if false:

```
(f 27)
1
(f 28)
0
(f 85)
1
(f 86)
0
```

Detailed version:

```
(define (sd x)   ; fn to find sum of digits
  (if (= x 0)
      0
      (+ (modulo x 10)
         (sd (/ (- x (modulo x 10)) 10)))))

(require math)
(define (f N)
  (if (= (for/sum ((i (factorize N)))
           (* (sd (list-ref i 0))
              (list-ref i 1)))
         (sd N)) 1 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Rust - 143 bytes

```
fn t(mut n:u32)->bool{let s=|k:u32| (2..=k).fold((0,k),|(a,m),_|(a+m%10,m/10));s(n).0==(2..n).fold(0,|mut a,d|{while n%d<1{n/=d;a+=s(d).0};a})}
```

borrowed python solution by @levitatinglion  ... at least this is shorter than Java...

[degolfed at play.rust-lang.org](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e2a467d637f009f3bea17115fae119aa)

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 39 chars, 78 bytes

```
{⍵≤0:0⋄0π⍵:0⋄(2×↑a)=+/a←+/¨{⍎¨⍕⍵}¨⍵,π⍵}
```

test:

```
  f←{⍵≤0:0⋄0π⍵:0⋄(2×↑a)=+/a←+/¨{⍎¨⍕⍵}¨⍵,π⍵}
  f¨0..10
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
  ⎕fmt {⍵,f⍵}¨18,22,13,666,¯265,0,1,4937775
┌8────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│┌2────┐ ┌2────┐ ┌2────┐ ┌2─────┐ ┌2──────┐ ┌2───┐ ┌2───┐ ┌2─────────┐│
││ 18 0│ │ 22 1│ │ 13 0│ │ 666 1│ │ ¯265 0│ │ 0 0│ │ 1 0│ │ 4937775 1││
│└~────┘ └~────┘ └~────┘ └~─────┘ └~──────┘ └~───┘ └~───┘ └~─────────┘2
└∊────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

## C (gcc), 177 Bytes

Defines a function `Q` that returns 0 for smith numbers and nonzero for non-smith numbers

```
#define r return
O(D,i){for(i=0;D>0;i+=D%10,D-=D%10,D/=10);r i;}D(O,o){for(o=1;o<O;)if(O%++o<1)r o;r O;}Q(p,q,i,j){if(p^(q=D(i=p))){for(j=0;p>1;q=D(p/=q))j+=O(q);r j^O(i);}r 1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc5Bb4MgGAbgu7/iSxcTvohRdNNulJ68kyY7Lk02RYfJUKk7GX@7E9vr5PISeOD9yrApy2V5qlStjQILVo2/1niSFFTjVHeWaBHz4hxzHYjCZzEtwkdGgsXILWg@F0TS7s47wXh3khx1TaQfBN2JoYVudZLPF9LTgWra4rRe91cyiGIt6BHvj9u1qz8z7o77SAyIbSAkGVxNe5VEI58tMD57UQTv6jZq08CXarS5wbeyyvv51Ibg5MG6eqvNWJODX8Eb@NWHOVBgRwoXwo6I/F@TJM4kyZ5h6fZPumeyLHNojT0VJtmLYy73XOxQvDvTNtKeeH5N8zzf6h5bp2dvWf4A)

Explanation:

```
// Return the sum of digits of D if D > 0, otherwise 0
O(D,i){
    // While D is greater than 0:
    // Add the last digit of D to i, and remove the last digit from D
    for(i=0;D>0;i+=D%10,D-=D%10,D/=10);
    return i;
}
// Return the smallest prime factor of O if O>1 else O
D(O,o){
    // Iterate over numbers less than O
    for(o=1;o<O;)
        // If O is divisible by o return o
        if(O%++o<1)
            return o;
    // Otherwise return O
    return O;
}
Q(p,q,i,j){
    // Set q to D(p) and i to p
    // If p != D(p) (i.e, p is composite and > 0)
    if(p^(q=D(i=p))){
        // Iterate over the prime factors of p and store their digit sum in j
        for(j=0;p>1;q=D(p/=q))
            j+=O(q);
        // i is the original value of p. If O(i)^j == 0, O(i) == j
        return j^O(i);
    }
    // If p was composite or < 0, return 1
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: [153 bytes](https://tio.run/##fc49b8MgEAbgPb8CJbJ0JxPF4NZOQ2gXdpS9ilT5o8JSDEbpZPm3u2B1LSwH3KP3rjl@N826HtquN2NHPPHd88ePOw0KZ0/Uh8pYkYfXiRV4KcSiQFOLc289WMmEvWqBpged5bm9MvTECk@0WG7g6EQNHXAO7UE6KWGSCox0iIExESOEe2cifruTnBCHXGqYMCQMdw0GxbI@vswIOO9IOM6b8dnDPmvJhWTt57inhJ0puQE7I4p/DefRcJ4yrNxyypSpqiqiUFLqyKvXyGJNuSKiIrnTtlJKvLyVdV1v4/6uUS/rLw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

### [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 122 bytes

```
n=>{int m=n,b=0,a=$"{n}".Sum(x=>x-'0');for(int i=2;i<m;i++)if(n%i==0){b+=$"{i}".Sum(x=>x-'0');n/=i;i=1;}return n>0&&a==b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZczBCoJAFIXhfU8xROkMao1aYzFel63atWitonAhrzAqCOKzmy7V7cf5T954eYPTq6M8RmrdrK5/CSsZTATJMAurgNwMpJvC6TjQeLx8uor3kPSeLW2hy9rwZYYQaIwrjY4jsOR0RgAphsxZMtxldAXUCL4eTdF2hhgl0rJSgEyPkz58DbbFG6ngJfcfQqwlCLbih1tRSm3JC9R9a3L3NANbye0ZRlG0lNMf)

Comment: [118 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZczNCoJAFEDhfU8xSOkMjuVPaTFel63atWitonAhrzAqCOKzmy6dth@cU3Ze2eHyHKhMkXpZtO03YzWDhSCbVmENkCzAlzkcrYlm6/weGj5CNnqO7wiJEKq61Vxh2ih0XYE1pxOmgZgKd0vQTBRdABVCoGZd9YMmRplv2zlAoeZFHT4a@@qFVPGaB3ch9hKGpgSRKXEcm@SF8c00/@@0AtvJ9RElSbKVyw8 "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online")